# transitionTo LoadingRoute in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to trigger the loading route on a controller action?
for example:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(
  actions:  
    new:  
      # transitionTo loading
      $.post(...).then (response) ->
        # deactivate loading
)
```

I would like to avoid adding a custom 'loading' property for each controller, and just use the built in LoadingRoute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember will transition to a route called `App.LoadingRoute` automatically, when the `model` hook of some route return a promise. For example:

```
App.PeopleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
      return fetchPeopleFromServer();
  }
});
```

So if you declare the `App.LodingRoute` and your template (data-template-name="loading") you will get the content of that template inserted in the page, while the promise isn't resolved. When it is finished the loading template is removed and the template of the current route is appended.

Some times you want the loading template to be inserted in some region of the page, by default it's just appended in the end. In that case you can use a outlet and override the renderTemplate to control where this template will be inserted. For example:

**Route**

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {            
        this.render('loading', { into: 'application', outlet: 'loading' })        
    }
});
```

**Template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div class="loading">{{outlet "loading"}}</div>
    ...
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

You can manually transition to `LoadingRoute` using `transitionTo('loading')` like the other declared routes. For example in a long task trigged in a route action:

```
someAction: function() {
    var route = this;
    route.transitionTo('loading');
    longTask().then(function() {
        route.transitionTo('index');
    });            
}
```

This is a jsfiddle showing this in action http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/JEqmq/

Comment: I know about the model promise, but this is good for fetching data, when you want to post data to the server, you will probably use a controller action instead of a route(correct me if I'm wrong). I would like to show the loading template from a controller function, is it possible with Ember?

Comment: Make sense you are right. I updated the answer and the fiddle. Basically you can transitionTo loading route manually. And after the task is finished, transition to another route, to change the loading message with a new template.

Comment: I had to add the loading route to the router for this to work, but like expected, now going back after invoking the action redirects me to the loading route instead of the original route. Is there a way to replace the template without effecting the browser history?

Comment: You can use `replaceWith` instead of `transitionTo` http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1663/edit. This I used the jsbin because is better to show browser history.

Comment: It's close, but still not perfect, the current page URL is still updated to '/loading', I would prefer to just render the loading template instead of changing the current URL.

Comment: I think that isn't possible, no in the public api. Because the LoadingRoute is like the others routes, and will change the location.hash, when some transition is performed. Internally ember change to the loading route, without perform a full transition, because this, the location.hash isn't updated. You can see this when clicking in the foo bar link. Here http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1907/edit I simulate this behavior, this implemenation isn't recommended is just to show how to change the route without update the hash.

Answer (score 3):

I've created the following two actions on application route

```
startLoading: function () {
  this.set('returnRoute', this.controller.get('currentRouteName'));
  this.intermediateTransitionTo('loading');      
},
endLoading: function () {
  this.intermediateTransitionTo(this.get('returnRoute'));     
}
```

Because transitions are intermediate, browser history is not affected and `didTransition`, `willTransition` actions are not fired on routes. `intermediateTransitionTo` is [part of the public API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_intermediateTransitionTo), so it should be safe to use.

Then I use these actions as

```
someAction: function() {
  var that = this;
  this.send('startLoading');
  longTask().then(function() {
    that.send('endLoading');
  });            
}
```